# Как получить комментарии пользователя, оставленные в конкретном сообществе в vk

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, pyqt5

Как получить все комментарии конкретного пользователя, оставленные на стене под постами в конкретном сообществе в vk?

Я рассмотрел все методы, существующие в vk api и пока не нашел способа выполнить данную задачу.

В качестве исходных данных в этой задаче даны id пользователя и id сообщества.

Вот пример того, как я это пытался реализовать:

```
for i in range(200):
    url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=%s&offset=%s&count=1" % (self.text1.toPlainText(), i)
    response = requests.get(url).text
    parsed_string = json.loads(response)

    url1="https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=%s&post_id=%s&count=100" %(self.text1.toPlainText(), parsed_string['response'][1]['items']['id'])

    response1 = requests.get(url1).text
    parsed_string1 = json.loads(response1)

    for j in range(1, len(parsed_string1['response'])):
        if parsed_string1['response'][j]['items']['from_id']==self.text2.toPlainText():
            item1 = QTableWidgetItem(parsed_string1['response'][j]['items']['text'])
            item2 = QTableWidgetItem(str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(parsed_string1['response'][j]['items']['date'])))
            self.tablewidget.setItem(i-1, 0, item1)
            self.tablewidget.setItem(i-1, 1, item2)
```

Но в таком случае происходят слишком частые запросы к серверу, да и этот вариант слишком муторный. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении мне двигаться и какие у вас есть мысли по этой теме.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VK API позволяет получить комментарии только для определенного объекта за один запрос. Например, можно получить список комментариев к конкретному посту на стене с помощью метода `wall.getComments`. Из этого списка нужно будет отобрать комментарии нужного пользователя.

Чтобы получить комментарии сразу к нескольким постам можно воспользоваться хранимыми процедурами, либо методом [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute). Метод execute в качестве параметра принимает код хранимой процедуры и выполняет его. ВКонтакте поддерживает хранимые процедуры с возможностью до 25 обращений к бд внутри одной процедуры. Таким образом мы можем получить за раз комментарии сразу к нескольким постам.

**Как написать процедуру**

---

Для этого можно воспользовать функционалом, который предоставляет ВК. Первым делом Вам понадобится приложение для доступа к API. Создать его можно [тут (кликабельно)](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) - кнопка `Создать приложение`. После создания зайдите в `редактирование` приложения, перейдите в раздел `Хранимые процедуры` и нажмите `Добавить новую процедуру`.

[image: Создание хранимой процедуры]

Теперь нужно написать саму процедуру.
Следующая процедура будет возвращать комментарии конкретного пользователя к 10 постам:

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var user_id = Args.user_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var post_count = Args.post_count;

if (post_count == null)
    post_count = 10;

// Получаем список постов
var posts = API.wall.get({
    "owner_id": owner_id,
    "offset": offset,
    "count" : 100,
});

var i = 0;
var userComments = {};

while(i < posts.items.length && i < post_count)
{
    var post_id = posts.items[i].id;
    var comments = API.wall.getComments({
        "owner_id": owner_id,
        "post_id": post_id,

        "count" : 100,
    });

    var j = 0;
    while(j < comments.items.length)
    {
        if (user_id == null || comments.items[j].from_id == user_id)
            userComments.push(comments.items[j]);

        j = j + 1;
    }

    i = i + 1;
}

return userComments;
```

**Как вызвать хранимую процедуру**

---

Вызвать можем 2мя способами:

- Через созданное ранее приложение. Это возможно только с помощью
  токена данного приложения.
- Через метод execute. Подойдет токен любого VK приложения.

Соответственно для получения списка комментраиев Вам нужно обратиться:

- В первом случае к
  `https://api.vk.com/method/execute.getCommentsFromPosts`, передав
  соответствующие параметры.
- Во втором к `https://api.vk.com/method/execute`, передав в качетве
  параметра `code` содержимое хранимой процедуры.

Comment: да за такой мануал на некоторых форумах немалые деньги берут)

Comment: @Skrim, огромное спасибо, очень подробный ответ, буду сейчас это изучать

Comment: @Skrim, а есть какой-нибудь способ получить комментарии более чем к 25 постам?

Comment: @Ramil, за один запрос к API нет. Вам нужно обернуть в цикл обращение к execute, увеличивая offset на каждом проходе на количество постов, комментарии к которым уже получили. Так вы сможете пройти по всем постам в сообществе и собрать комментарии. По прежнему придется выполнять какое-то количество запросов, но намного меньше, чем было раньше. Приведенная в ответе процедура возвращает комментарии нужного пользователя (если параметр user_id передан), или все сразу.

Comment: @Skrim, сделал как вы сказали, выдает ошибку: "Runtime error occurred during code invocation: Too many operations"
https://pp.vk.me/c836227/v836227428/14b30/-Ed4u5Qh0ME.jpg

Comment: @Skrim, 
Скрины: https://pp.vk.me/c836227/v836227428/14b39/ZY7pG1ix69k.jpg
Код ошибки 13, в официальной документации для vk api нет информации об этой ошибке. Не понятно чем она вызвана, так как это и не из-за слишком частых запросов (код ошибки 6), и не из-за большого числа однотипных действий (код ошибки 9)

Comment: @Skrim, я попробовал испытать виджет в другой группе и он возвратил комментарии конкретного пользователя из первых 96 записей, а потом виджет закрылся сам по себе

Comment: Видимо есть еще какие-то ограничения. Попробуйте уменьшить `post_count` до 10. В разных сообществах дает получать комменты к разному количеству постов. С чем связано не знаю, нужно спрашивать у поддержки вк. Например, при парсинге пользователей сообщества у меня выполняются все 25 запросов, подобных ограничений не возникает.

Comment: @Skrim, пробовал сейчас изменять это значение, ошибка пропала. Сейчас решаю проблему с вылетом из виджета. Я понял корень проблемы: если в посте содержится смайлик, то приложение вылетает. Пока не понял как решить данную проблему.

Comment: @Skim, сам смайлик в выводе хранимой процедуры представляется как &#128523.

Comment: @Skim, хотя при переносе комментариев в таблицу QTableWidget все отображается нормально, так что проблема решена, тема закрыта, большущее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Ramil, всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: @Anamorf Выяснилось, что код из Ответа возвращает лишь первую сотню комментариев из каждого обрабатываемого поста. Возможно, уважаемый Автор обратит внимание и расширит это количество на сколько возможное в рамках процедуры (вроде, можно до 2500).

Comment: @iskander1220: Тут все зависит от Вашей задачи. Мы можем сделать получение большего количества комментариев, но тогда уменьшится количество обрабатываемых постов. Если нужно получать все комменты, то это хорошее решение. Я лишь привел пример как пользоваться методом `Execute`, остальное возлагаю на Вас, экспериментируйте :)