# Как получить через wall.get (VK Api), посты за сегодня?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как получить через wall.get (VK Api), посты именно за сегодня?

Answer (score 3):

У метода wall.get, нет такой возможности. Вы можете самостоятельно проверять дату публикации.
Вам вк отдает объект в котором есть параметр дата, вот и сравнивайте ее с сегодняшней.

Comment: вообще-то можно, сделав хитренький запрос в запросе

Comment: Пример покажите?

Comment: пример уже будет ответом)) достаточно посмотреть на метод [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute) и написать нужный код в нём. Там можно фильтровать данные, выполнять запрос в запросе и прочее.

Comment: К сожалению сейчас нет время, я обязательно посмотрю подробней. А Вы все же, дайте ответ человеку если можете, я думаю он будет благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Есть следующие варианты:

- Методом `wall.get` получаем список постов и самостоятельно отбираем нужные, сравнивая дату.
- Можно воспользоваться хранимыми процедурами и методом [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute). Нужно написать подходящую процедуру, которая сразу будет возвращать список требуемых постов. Пример использования [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604524/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2-vk/604538#604538)

Comment: Интересно, каким это образом вы предлагаете в `execute` делать проверку по дате. Передавать в него таймштамп начала дня и таймштамп конца дня?

Comment: @terron, да, придется передавать, это можно посчитать за минус. Плюсом будет большее количество возвращаемых постов, если их будет более 100. Тут конечно проще обойтись простым `wall.get` и проверять даты самостоятельно. Но если вдруг понадобится что-то более сложное, с бОльшим объемом данных, `execute` - хорошее решение.