# VK API можно ли с помощью wall.get вывести посты за определенный период?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Например, посты за месяц. Ограничение в 100 последних постов не позволяет вывести статистику за месяц.

Comment: Никто не запрещает вызвать wall.get несколько раз с разным offset и получить сколько угодно записей

Comment: Это да, это уже решил. А есть ли вариант добавить в хранимые процедуры период, за который нужно вывести данные?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить через wall.get (VK Api), посты за сегодня?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607064/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-wall-get-vk-api-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f)