# Получение комментариев и участников сообщества vk.com — методом execute (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Возник вопрос по предложенному [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604524/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2-vk) решению, касающемуся получения комментариев пользователя, оставленных в конкретном сообществе на vk. Вроде, воспроизвёл у себя в приложении процедуру, подставил ID профиля и ID случайного пользователя из комментария к первому посту к этому профилю (менял их местами), но всякий раз выводится сообщение об ошибке. Прошу взглянуть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixeP.png

Кроме того, по тому же методу не удаётся задействовать следующий код ([отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248725/#tag1)), получающий список участников сообщества:

```
VK.init({
    apiId: 6456476 // ID вашего приложения VK
});

var membersGroups = []; // массив участников группы
getMembers(30666517);

// получаем информацию о группе и её участников
function getMembers(group_id) {
    VK.Api.call('groups.getById', {group_id: group_id, fields: 'photo_50,members_count', v: '5.27'}, function(r) {
            if(r.response) {
                $('.group_info')
                .html('<img src="' + r.response[0].photo_50 + '"/><br/>' 
                    + r.response[0].name
                    + '<br/>Участников: ' + r.response[0].members_count);
                getMembers20k(group_id, r.response[0].members_count); // получаем участников группы и пишем в массив membersGroups
            }
    });
}

// получаем участников группы, members_count - количество участников
function getMembers20k(group_id, members_count) {
    var code =  'var members = API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": ' + group_id + ', "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": ' + membersGroups.length + '}).items;' // делаем первый запрос и создаем массив
            +   'var offset = 1000;' // это сдвиг по участникам группы
            +   'while (offset < 25000 && (offset + ' + membersGroups.length + ') < ' + members_count + ')' // пока не получили 20000 и не прошлись по всем участникам
            +   '{'
                +   'members = members + "," + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": ' + group_id + ', "v": "5.27", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": (' + membersGroups.length + ' + offset)}).items;' // сдвиг участников на offset + мощность массива
                +   'offset = offset + 1000;' // увеличиваем сдвиг на 1000
            +   '};'
            +   'return members;'; // вернуть массив members
    
    VK.Api.call("execute", {code: code}, function(data) {
        if (data.response) {
            membersGroups = membersGroups.concat(JSON.parse("[" + data.response + "]")); // запишем это в массив
            $('.member_ids').html('Загрузка: ' + membersGroups.length + '/' + members_count);
            if (members_count >  membersGroups.length) // если еще не всех участников получили
                setTimeout(function() { getMembers20k(group_id, members_count); }, 333); // задержка 0.333 с. после чего запустим еще раз
            else // если конец то
                alert('Ура тест закончен! В массиве membersGroups теперь ' + membersGroups.length + ' элементов.');
        } else {
            alert(data.error.error_msg); // в случае ошибки выведем её
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки, возвращаемой vk.

Comment: По первому примеру, оказалось, ошибался — просто на выбранных мной IDсообщества/IDпользователя, процедура отчего-то не срабатывала. Осталось неясным, что прописывать в `offset` и в `post_count` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbJVV.png), чтобы охватывались все посты указанного в `user_id` пользователя без пропусков.

По второму примеру следующая ошибка при попытке запуска: https://i.imgur.com/KglPnqh.png 
И при попытке сохранения процедуры: https://i.imgur.com/xAc0pCf.png

Comment: (на счёт второго примера)Этот код для js. Он не для вставки его в процедуры или execute. Ваш код [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixeP.png) вполне рабочий.
В данной Вами ссылке на ответ в другом вопросе всё предельно ясно объясняется, как и что делать с этим кодом.
Вам нужно передавать аргументы к **execute.getCommentsFromPosts** . Например `execute.getCommentsFromPosts?post_count=10&offset=0&user_id=1&owner_id=1`

Comment: А также попрошу Вас откорректировать вопрос

Comment: Ясно, значит я не так понял инструкцию с Хабра, где код увязывался с `execute`. В остальном, вопросы вызывает нестандартное поведение команды (выполняю по кнопке из "Хранимых процедур") в двух сообществах: в одном сообществе, если в поле `post_count` указать цифру 25 (не заполняя поля `user_id` и `offset`) — выводится окно "Runtime error occurred during code invocation: Too many operations". В другом сообществе, где комментариев и активности меньше — команда и на 25 отрабатывает, хотя первое заработает только на 5. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Более предпочтительна была бы возможность получения максимального количества комментариев к конкретному посту через `execute`. Возможна ли здесь такая настройка?

Comment: За 1 запрос вы сможете получить не более 2500 комментариев (25*100) . Это указано в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments). Т.к. вы можете делать 25 запросов за 1 запрос к *execute*, мы можете получить не более 25*100 комментариев

Comment: Судя по подсчётам в Notepad++ — там и 500 комментариев не набирается, хотя проверял на крупном сообществе. Возможно, они намеренно сокращают выдачу. В любом случае, так и не разобрался в регламенте перебора страниц и требуемого для этого шага. Например, в одном сообществе последовательно ввел в начальные комментарии цифры от одного до десяти, потом начал получать их с этого сообщества по своему ID и приходили они в каком-то непоследовательном непонятном виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Вам требуется использовать метод *execute*

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/execute) к этому методу предельно ясно сказано, что этот метод позволяет выполнять **до 25 запросов** к **API** за **1 запрос** к методу.

На сколько я Вас понял, Вам требуется собрать все комментарии с поста(если нет, пишите в комментарии).
Но здесь сразу нужно поставить такие ограничения:

Т.к. запросов всего **25**, следовательно мы можем получить **25 * 100** комментариев.(*100 потому что за 1 запрос к [wall.getComments](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments) мы получим не более 100 комментариев*)

Следующий пункт - сделать код, который будет эти 2500 комментариев доставать из определённого поста.

```
var post_id = Args.post_id;
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var count = Args.count;
var offset = Args.offset;

if(post_id == null || owner_id == null){
    return {"count": 0, "items": []};  // Если параметры не заданы, возвращаем пустой массив
}
if(count == null){
    count = 10; // Значение по умолчанию
}
if(offset == null){
    offset = 0; // Значение по умолчанию
}
var i = 0;
var items = [];
while(i < 25 && count > items.length){
    var cur_count = count - items.length;
    if(cur_count > 100){
        cur_count = 100;
    }
    items = items + API.wall.getComments({"owner_id": owner_id, "post_id": post_id, "offset": offset+100*i, "count": cur_count})["items"];
    i = i + 1;
}
return {"count": items.length, "items": items};
```

Этот код можно передавать в качестве аргумента к *execute* (аргумент *code*), а вместе с этим аргументом и аргументы `post_id`, `ower_id` и остальные.
Второй вариант - создать процедуру в своём приложении и уже вызывать с токеном, полученным **для Вашего приложения** вызывать эту процедуру с параметрами `owner_id`, `post_id` и остальные.

## Как получить больше, чем 2500 комментариев?

Для этого Вам всего лишь требуется вызывать этот код несколько раз с разными параметрами `offset`(постоянно увеличивая его на 2500)

Пример на *python3*:

```
from math import ceil
import json,time

import vk_api
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='...')  # Ваш токен
api = vk.get_api()

posts = api.wall.getById(posts='{owner_id}_{post_id}'.format(owner_id='<owner_id>', post_id='<post_id>'))  # Где <owner_id> - id пользователя/группы, post_id - id поста. *см. комментарии после кода

if not posts:
    print('No posts found!')

post = posts[0]
posts = []

for offset in range(ceil(post['comments']['count'] // 2500)):
    posts.extend(api.execute.getCommentsFromPost(owner_id='<owner_id>', post_id='<post_id>', offset=2500*offset, count=2500)['items'])  # тут всё по аналогии, как и в первый раз
    time.sleep(0.34)  # избегаем flood control

with open('output.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(posts, file)
```

Следует заметить, что id сообществ следует указывать с минусом, например `-1`.
Также стоит упомянуть, что при многократном вызывании одного и того же метода, ВК блокирует доступ к нему.

Comment: Сейчас начал тестировать Ваш первый код для `execute` и так понимаю, он однократно способен возвратить только 100 комментариев — то есть столько же, сколько возвращает стандартная команда без использования `execute`? Если она не работает в цикле и не получает 25 раз по 100 — в чём смысл ее использования?

Comment: Почему 100?Он должен не более 2500

Comment: Прошу прощения. Сейчас исправлю. 1 букву забыл

Comment: Попробуйте сейчас.

Comment: Вот так спасибо!

Comment: Уважаемый, а если бы комментариев в посте было больше 2500 (тестирую на меньшем количестве) — каким бы тогда должен был быть `offset` для команды? Сначала "0", потом "1", "2", "3" и т.д.?

Comment: Нет. 0, 2500, 5000, 7500 и тд

Comment: Уважаемый, чтобы возвращалась инфа о количестве лайков к комментариям (need_likes=1), куда в коде можно прописать настройку?

Comment: 4 строка снизу. Добавить `..., "need_likes":1}`