# Получение комментариев к посту ВКонтакта методом execute (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Имеется ли процедура для [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute), с помощью которой можно получать комментарии к посту, чей ID явно не указан? То есть, по номеру поста со стены? К примеру, по этому принципу работает следующий код ([из Ответа отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604524/)), но выяснилось, что он возвращает лишь первую сотню комментариев (кстати, если указать user_id — возвратит только комментарии этого пользователя) —

```
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604524/
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var user_id = Args.user_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var post_count = Args.post_count;

if (post_count == null)
    post_count = 1;         // количество обрабатываемых постов

// Получаем список постов
var posts = API.wall.get({
    "owner_id": owner_id,
    "offset": offset,
    "count" : 100,
});

var i = 0;
var userComments = {};

while(i < posts.items.length && i < post_count)
{
    var post_id = posts.items[i].id;
    var comments = API.wall.getComments({
        "owner_id": owner_id,
        "post_id": post_id,

        "count" : 100,
    });

    var j = 0;
    while(j < comments.items.length)
    {
        if (user_id == null || comments.items[j].from_id == user_id)
            userComments.push(comments.items[j]);

        j = j + 1;
    }

    i = i + 1;
}

return userComments;
```

А вот этот код ([отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780304/)), возвращающий 2500 комментариев, требует явного указания идентификатора поста:

```
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780304/
// count  --> 2500 / по умолчанию --> 10
// offset --> 0, 2500, 5000, 7500 и тд
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var post_id = Args.post_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var count = Args.count;

if(post_id == null || owner_id == null){
    return {"count": 0, "items": []};  // Если параметры не заданы, возвращаем пустой массив
}
if(count == null){
    count = 10; // Значение по умолчанию
}
if(offset == null){
    offset = 0; // Значение по умолчанию
}
var i = 0;
var items = [];
while(i < 25 && count > items.length){
    var cur_count = count - items.length;
    if(cur_count > 100){
        cur_count = 100;
    }
    items = items + API.wall.getComments({"owner_id": owner_id, "post_id": post_id, "offset": offset+100*i, "count": cur_count, "need_likes":1})["items"];
    i = i + 1;
}
return {"count": items.length, "items": items};
```

Вопрос заключается в совмещении функционала из обоих кодов, чтобы вызывать процедуру можно было с указанием смещения `offset`, а не с указанием номера поста. Это позволило бы выводить либо производить поиск по юзеру среди всех коммов, без необходимости заранее узнавать и прописывать идентификаторы постов. Может быть, для этого в первый код (настроенный на обработку одного поста за один раз) достаточно будет добавить последовательный вызов методов со смещением, как в следующем коде, получающем за раз 500 постов? —

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id; 
var offset   = Args.offset; 
 
return 
    API.wall.get({ 
        "owner_id" : owner_id, 
        "count"    : 100, 
        "filter"   : "owner", 
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 0 * 100 
    }).items +  
    API.wall.get({ 
        "owner_id" : owner_id, 
        "count"    : 100, 
        "filter"   : "owner", 
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 1 * 100 
    }).items + 
    API.wall.get({ 
        "owner_id" : owner_id, 
        "count"    : 100, 
        "filter"   : "owner", 
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 2 * 100 
    }).items +  
    API.wall.get({ 
        "owner_id" : owner_id, 
        "count"    : 100, 
        "filter"   : "owner", 
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 3 * 100 
    }).items + 
    API.wall.get({ 
        "owner_id" : owner_id, 
        "count"    : 100, 
        "filter"   : "owner", 
        "offset"   : parseInt(offset) + 4 * 100 
    }).items;
```

Comment: @Anamorf [в продолжение разговора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604524/) (на который у меня там недостаточно прав) позволю себе сказать, что в задачу не всегда входят пропуски в комментариях :) Просто хотелось универсальности, поскольку код лучший на эту тему, позволяя извлекать коменты по ИД, а посты — без привязки к ИД, вместо которых можно использовать порядковые номера в аргументах. Если сочтёте возможным взглянуть — выше мой вопрос на этот счёт.

Comment: Забыл ещё сказать, что преимущество этого кода без привязки к идентификаторам постов в том, что с ним можно будет отслеживать и накапливать на inoreader.com комментарии со стен — именно благодаря порядковым номерам (вместо ID постов, которые иначе надо заранее знать).

Comment: @Anamorf То есть, достаточно будет на [feed43.com](http://feed43.com) создать RSS-ленту с `offset=1`, потом вторую ленту с `offset=2` — и так далее, в меру необходимости. А затем на [inoreader.com](https://inoreader.com) объединить эти ленты в единую ленту и получать примерно получасовые обновления.

Comment: Прямо сейчас пытался понять, чего вы хотите, но так и не понял. Попробуйте [переформулировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) вопрос, что бы стало понятнее, если вам всё ещё нужен ответ на него.